# Blank Page with React when fetching video from Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, video, firebase-storage

I am trying to display a background video on my web app after fetching it from firebase storage. The code looks something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { storage } from "../firebase";
const videoRef = storage.ref().child('<filename>');

export default function Dashboard() {
    const [videoURL, setVideoUrl] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        videoRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            setVideoUrl(url);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <video width="400" autoPlay muted loop>
                <source src={videoURL} type="video/mp4"/>
                Your Browser does not support HTML video.
            </video>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The resulting page is blank, but inspecting the element via dev tools shows the video element with the correct url. In fact, if I just copy the url and hard code it as src it works just fine.
I assume there is some issue related to React not refreshing after updating the url but I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, really no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render `<video>` tag when the videoURL is available.

```
return (
    <div>
        {!!videoURL && (
            <video width="400" autoPlay muted loop>
                <source src={videoURL} type="video/mp4"/>
                Your Browser does not support HTML video.
            </video>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, even without the double not!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use a component to do that.

i found react-player very easy to use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

example of usage:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

// Render a YouTube video player
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the videoRef inside the dependency array on the useEffect.

Comment: I tried    useEffect(() => {
        videoRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            setVideoUrl(url);
        });
   }, [videoURL]);
Same result